# JSON schema for key (unknown column name): value (list of integers) pairs

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to make JSON schema for JSON which looks something like that (It's for constructing regressors with delays.):

{'x1': [1,6,2], 'col5': [0], 'y': [1, 6, 3, 8]}

I don't know column names and neither the length of the lists in advance. The only thing I know is that column name should be a string and list of values an array. Any advice how to construct it? 
I'm open to more suitable JSON format and it's scheme.

Answer (score 2):

Although is is possible to achieve with `patternProperties` of `.*` pattern the more straightforward way is to use `additionalProperties` schema attribute, e.g.:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": { 
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
       "type": "integer"
    }
  }
}
```

In this example I also restricted array element type to integer.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect use-case for JSON Schema. It allows you add as few or as many constraints as are are needed. The following schema requires that the JSON be an object where all properties must be an array. An array of what? It could be anything. It's unconstrained.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    ".*": { "type": "array" }
  }
}
```